# Webview not working in react-native-element Overlay

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-native-elements

I'm using [react-native-element](https://react-native-elements.github.io/react-native-elements/) for ready-made components in my application and using [Overlay](https://react-native-elements.github.io/react-native-elements/docs/overlay.html) to show modals through out the application. 
Now the issue is I've a Modal in which I want to show Webview but it doesn't showup on the screen.
My modal code looks like this

```
export const Modal = ({ visible, showCrossBtn, setModalVisible, backgroundColor, children }) => {

    return (
        <Overlay
            isVisible={visible}
            fullScreen={false}
            height="auto"
            overlayBackgroundColor={backgroundColor}
            overlayStyle={styles.overlay}
            onBackdropPress={() => setModalVisible(false)}>
            <View style={styles.dialogBox}>
                {
                    showCrossBtn && <TouchableOpacity style={[styles.crossPosition, styles.crossStyling]} onPress={() => setModalVisible(false)}>
                        <Icon name="cross" type="entypo" color={colors.gray} size={30} />
                    </TouchableOpacity>
                }

                <View style={styles.body}>
                    {children}
                </View>
            </View>
        </Overlay>
    )
}
```

In my basic component

```
export const Home = ({ }) => {
  return (
    ....
    ....
    <Modal
      visible={this.props.visible}
      setModalVisible={this.props.setModalVisible}
      backgroundColor={colors.lightgray}
      showCrossBtn={false}
      >
      <WebView
                style={[{ height: 20 }, styles.webView]}
                originWhitelist={['*']}
                ref={e => webview = e}
                source={{ html: '<p>HELLO WORLD</p>'}} />
    </Modal>

  )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `WebView` in modals can be tricky due to the height and width.

To solve the issue, I've created a [Snack](https://snack.expo.io/r1H4FSHML) using `react-native-elements` [Overlay](https://react-native-elements.github.io/react-native-elements/docs/overlay.html) component and `WebView`. I used some of your code and remove any redundant code for brevity.

Use iOS or Android simulator to run the snack. You can also use your physical device to run the snack using expo app.

Snack - https://snack.expo.io/r1H4FSHML